# How to use "handle SIGILL nostop noprint" with a gdbserver?

Tags: ida, gdb

I have a program linked against libcrypto.so. If i run the program in gdb i'll get the following error:
"Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction."
I researched a bit and found out that it is a problem of libcrypto and that i can ignore that signals using "handle SIGILL nostop noprint" before running. Works in gdb, but does not with a gdbserver.

Question:
How can i use "handle SIGILL nostop noprint" with a gdbserver? If i connect IDA to my gdbserver it always crash with the SIGILL, Illegal instruction error message.

Comment: Can an init file be used https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~learn/debugging/modules/gdb_init_file/#gdb-user-initialization-file ?